# How can I insert into an Oracle Database using HTML fields?

Tags: php, html, oracle

I am working on a website where I ask users to fill out a form, made in HTML. The form is then used to create an entity in the Oracle database using php.

Here is the HTML form

```
<input required type="number" name="pid" value = "<?php echo $pid;?>">
<input required type="text" name="title" value = "<?php echo $title;?>">
<input required type="number" name="price" value = "<?php echo $price;?>">
 <input type="number" name="number" value = "<?php echo $classNum;?>">
<input type="text" name="department" value = "<?php echo $classDept;?>">
<input required type="text" name="author" value = "<?php echo $author;?>">
<input type="text" name="isbn" value = "<?php echo $isbn;?>">
<input type="text" name="firstName" value = "<?php echo $contactfn;?>">
<input type="text" name="lastName" value = "<?php echo $contactln;?>">


     $postid = $_POST["pid"];
     $title = $_POST["title"];
     $price = $_POST["price"];
     $classNum = $_POST["number"];
     $classDept = $_POST["department"];
     $author = $_POST["author"];
     $isbn = $_POST["isbn"];
     $contactfn = $_POST["firstName"];
     $contactln = $_POST["lastName"];
     $contactinfo = $_POST["contactinfo"];
```

When it comes to the php to insert into the database, here is the query I am working on. I can't get it to properly insert. I believe there is some issue with the concatenation/conversion from PHP to HTML to SQLPlus.

The following query works:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO Class VALUES (3,313, 'MATH')";
```

However, when trying to read from the form using this query, it fails:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO Class VALUES ('$postid', '$classNum', '$classDept')";
```

Can someone get me pointed in the right direction? What am I missing in the syntax?

Comment: fails **HOW**? did you check if your form submits the proper data? Did you check if php is receiving that data? Did you look and see what the query string you're building looks like? Did you execute that query at all?

Comment: The form refreshes and auto-deletes the info as if it was submitted. Like I said, I tried the other query and it works with hard-coded values. The connection has been checked, and it connects successfully. How can I check to see what the query string i'm building looks like?

Comment: `var_dump($query, $_POST)`, etc... that's all standard/basic debugging.

Comment: echo $query; Also, if this is on you own machine (development server) then turn on all error reporting so you can see any errors that php is throwing.

Comment: Thanks Jeff, this is not a personal machine. Campus server. Not familiar with standard PHP/HTML debugging.

Comment: "It fails" - hardly helping us to help you. There could a number of reasons it might fail, and each one would have a distinct separate cause. A good point to start would be to post the error you are getting, and also a "DESCRIBE" of the table.

Comment: Please first read up about SQL Injection - So you can at least get into that habit of preventing it